# How to get my Python program to pass an online grading system?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

> Question:
>
> - The hand is displayed.
>
>   - The user may input a word or a single period (the string ".") 
>       to indicate they're done playing
>   - Invalid words are rejected, and a message is displayed asking
>       the user to choose another word until they enter a valid word or "."
>   - When a valid word is entered, it uses up letters from the hand.
>   - After every valid word: the score for that word is displayed,
>       the remaining letters in the hand are displayed, and the user
>       is asked to input another word.
>   - The sum of the word scores is displayed when the hand finishes.
>   - The hand finishes when there are no more unused letters or the user inputs a "."

```
  hand: dictionary (string -> int)
  wordList: list of lowercase strings
```

I am trying to write a code for my Python programming online course. However, I am getting  an error :

> ERROR: Failed to display hand correctly - be sure 'Current Hand' and the display of the hand are on the same line!

Here is my code :

```
def playHand(hand, wordList, n):
    total = 0
    while True: 
        print("\nCurrent Hand:",)
        displayHand(hand)
        entered = input('Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: ') 
        if entered == '.':
            print ("Goodbye! Total score: " + str(total) +" points.")
            break
        if isValidWord(entered, hand, wordList) == False:
            print ("Invalid word, please try again.")  
        else: 
            total += getWordScore(entered, n)
            print (str(entered), "earned", getWordScore(entered,n), "points. Total:", str(total))
            hand = updateHand(hand, entered)
        if calculateHandlen(hand) == 0:
            print ("\nRun out of letters. Total score: " + str(total) +" points.")
            break
```

Comment: We can't help, since obviously you haven't posted all of your code. NOWHERE in what you did post does "failed to display hand" show up.

Comment: @MarcB presumably that's from some kind of automated grading system (looks like MIT 6.00x). That said, they don't show e.g. `displayHand` either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: maybe. but regardless, there's NO code given for `displayHand` or `isValidWord`, etc...

Comment: Well, are "Current Hand" and the display of the hand on the same line?  What is the output of this?  What is the *expected* output?  We're not in the same online course as you, you have to describe the problem and where you're stuck.

Comment: "Current Hand" and the display of the hand are not on the same line, this is what I am getting as error.

Comment: @MridulaManish: So, when you debug this, what causes the other line to display?  Keep in mind that none of us know what `displayHand()` does.  We can't help you without any meaningful information about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your code already:

```
def displayHand(hand):
    for letter in hand.keys():
        for j in range(hand[letter]):
            print(letter,end=" ")       # print all on the same line
    print()                             # print an empty line
```

Use end=" " in your print statement!!